# work with TapJoy from Android

Tags: android, tapjoy

I need to get list of some applications from TapJoy, and then display them in my Android project. Have TapJoy a special SDK for working with Android (something like AdWhirl SDK for Android)?

Answer (score 4):

I registered a tapjoy account, created a sample project and found this:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/tapjoy/sdks/TapjoyConnectSDK_Android_v8.0.1.zip

That is the andriod SDK for tapjoy.

Comment: Sorry, I don't even have an android device!

Comment: You can find the tapjoy sample application in the zip file that you download now. www.tapjoy.com/sdk

Answer (score 1):

Tapjoy has a [Knowledge Center](https://dev.tapjoy.com/sdk-integration/android/) with all the information you need on integrating an Android device.  Have you looked there?  They even have code samples!  That's how we got our application setup to use their SDK.

Comment: The link is dead.