# TapJoy In Android Full Integration

Tags: android, tapjoy

How to integrate Tap-joy In my Android Application.

I already Search on Google but nothing useful  find about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **FIRST** result on google search with keywords "How to integrate Tap-joy In my Android Application."
[work with TapJoy from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421411/work-with-tapjoy-from-android)